# How to fix inputting the same character multiple times as a guess?(Beginner Python project - Hangman game)

Tags: python

Inputting the same character multiple times doesn’t work.
Here is my code for the relevant issue
Please be noted that I’ve unnecessarily complicated my code by working on it for a long time to resolve the problem.
I’d really appreciate a correction from anybody.
Thanks in advance

```py
def gamefunction():
    global chosenword
    global wordlen
    global attempts

    chosenwordlist = []

    tally = 1
    print("\nThe word to guess is....\n")
    print(chosenword)

    display = "_" * len(chosenword)
    print(display)

    for i in chosenword:
        chosenwordlist.append(i)

    print(chosenwordlist)

    while tally <= int(attempts):
        userchoice = input()
        guessedletters = []
        sameletterguess = []

        if len(userchoice.strip()) == 1:
            occcurence1 = chosenword.find(userchoice)

            if (userchoice in chosenword) and (chosenwordlist.count(userchoice) == 1):
                display = display[:occcurence1] + userchoice + display[occcurence1 + 1:]
                guessedletters.append(userchoice)

            elif (userchoice in chosenword) and (chosenwordlist.count(userchoice) > 1):
                sameletterguess.append(userchoice)
                display = display[:occcurence1] + userchoice + display[occcurence1 + 1:]
                guessedletters.append(userchoice)

                print(sameletterguess)
                print(sameletterguess.count(userchoice))

                if sameletterguess.count(userchoice) == 2:
                    occurence2 = chosenword.find(userchoice,chosenword.find(userchoice)+1)
                    display = display[:occurence2] + userchoice + display[occurence2 + 1:]
                    guessedletters.append(userchoice)
                    print(sameletterguess)

                elif sameletterguess.count(userchoice) == 3:
                    occurence3 = chosenword.find(userchoice, chosenword.find(userchoice,chosenword.find(userchoice)+1)+1)
                    display = display[:occurence3] + userchoice + display[occurence3 + 1:]
                    guessedletters.append(userchoice)
                    print(sameletterguess)

                elif sameletterguess.count(userchoice) == 4:
                    occurence4 = chosenword.find(userchoice, chosenword.find(userchoice, chosenword.find(userchoice,chosenword.find(userchoice)+1)+1)+1)
                    display = display[:occurence4] + userchoice + display[occurence4 + 1:]
                    guessedletters.append(userchoice)
                    print(sameletterguess)

            else:
                print("Wrong guess")
                tally = tally + 1

            print("\n" + display)

            if display == chosenword:
                tally = int(attempts) + 1
                print("Congratulations\nYou guessed the word correctly")

        else:
            print("Invalid input\nEnter only a single letter\n")
            print(display)
```

For further understanding -
It seems like the code doesn't run through the if-else loop nested within the  'if len(userchoice.strip()) == 1:' loop

Comment: Could you please fix indentation of your code? Also: What is the expected behaviour, what doesn't work, and what's the minimal code that reproduces your error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be much more easier for others to help you if you could [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At present, the code seems unnecessarily long.

Comment: @Dschoni It works fine if the randomly chosen word has each letter only once. for example, ‘word’.
but if a word like ‘boots’ is chosen then the user has to input ‘o’ twice, right? but in this case, it is not possible to input ‘o’ twice as an answer. it doesn’t work. My guess is, the nested if loop starting from 'if len(userchoice.strip()) == 2:' doesn't run for some reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution for your problem is as below.
Extensive comments inside the code.

```
#Defining globals. Note: Using globals is bad practice, use function arguments instead
chosenword = 'boot'
attempts = 4

def gamefunction():
    global chosenword
    global attempts
    
    #Create needed extra variables directly from input
    wordlen = len(chosenword)
    chosenwordlist = list(chosenword)

    tally = 1
    print("\nThe word to guess is....\n")
    print(chosenword)
    
    #Added whitespace for better wordlength visualisation
    display = "_ " * wordlen
    print(display)

    print(chosenwordlist)

    #This holds the letters that have been guessed already
    guessedletters = []

    while tally <= int(attempts):
        display = ''
        userchoice = input()

        if len(userchoice.strip()) == 1:
            #check if the guess is part of the word to guess
            if userchoice in chosenwordlist:
                # Check if letter has been guessed before
                if userchoice in guessedletters:
                    print('You tried that letter already')
                    continue
                else:
                    # Add the guessed letter to the list of all guessed letters and create display
                    guessedletters.append(userchoice)
                    for i in range(wordlen):
                        if chosenwordlist[i] in guessedletters:
                            display+=chosenwordlist[i]
                        else:
                            display+='_ '
            else:
                print("Wrong guess")
                tally = tally + 1

            print("\n" + display)

            if display == chosenword:
                tally = int(attempts) + 1
                print("Congratulations\nYou guessed the word correctly")

        else:
            print("Invalid input\nEnter only a single letter\n")
            print(display)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code is perfect. However, I'm trying to get the user type the character 'o' twice as it has two 'o' in the word boot. I must say, the for loop you've replaced instead of string slicing is a smart technique here

Comment: In general, these kind of questions should go on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you get them working, but want the code to be improved. The hangman rules I know use a guessed letter as often as it occurs in the word. You could change that by removing letters from the letter list when "used" in a word. In this case, you should also allow user input with more than one letter. Try my solution with the word `boots` and guess `o` as a single letter -  It will fill both instances of `o` in the word to be guessed in a single guess. This is expected behaviour for hangman.